# How to change class Components into function Components?

Tags: reactjs, components

Does anyone know how to change the class components into functional components?

I just learned "Functional Components" in REACT and I am having a tough time converting class components into functional components for understanding problems and analyzing. I want to use a functional approach for understanding states and life cycle methods and how that works in the concept of the HOOK.

How we can achieve this?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css"

class EditExercise extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            description: '',
            duration: 0,
            date: new Date()
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/'
         + window.location.toString().split('/')[4])
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                username: response.data.username,
                description: response.data.description,
                duration: response.data.duration,
                date: new Date(response.data.date)
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    
    onChangeUsername(event) {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeDescription(event) {
        this.setState({
            description: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeDuration(event) {
        this.setState({
            duration: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeDate(date) {
        this.setState({
            date: date
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Exercise Edited!");

        const exercise = {
            username: this.state.username,
            description: this.state.description,
            duration: this.state.duration,
            date: this.state.date
        }

        console.log(exercise);

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/update/'
         + window.location.toString().split('/')[4] , exercise)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        window.location = '/';
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "EditExercise">
                <h1>Edit Exercise</h1>
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username: </label>
                        <input
                         type="text"
                         required
                         value={this.state.username}
                         onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Description: </label>
                        <input
                         type="text"
                         required
                         value={this.state.description}
                         onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Duration: </label>
                        <input
                         type="text"
                         required
                         value={this.state.duration}
                         onChange={this.onChangeDuration}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Date: </label>
                        <div>
                            <DatePicker
                             selected={this.state.date}
                             onChange={this.onChangeDate}>
                            </DatePicker>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                         type="submit"
                         value="Edit Exercise Log" 
                         onClick={this.onSubmit}
                         ></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EditExercise;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the basics of hooks. You can follow these 3 steps.

1. You can try and move all your state properties of `this.state` from the class component to the `useState` of the functional component

Class

```js
class Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      description: "",
      duration: 0,
      date: new Date(),
    };
  }
}
```

Functional

We can create state at the top of the component

```js
function Component() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  // ...etc
}
```

---

2. Component life cycles

In the functional components we have a `useEffect` hook which we can use to handle the class equivalent `componentDidMount`.

Class

```js
class Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:5000/exercises/" +
          window.location.toString().split("/")[4]
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          username: response.data.username,
          description: response.data.description,
          duration: response.data.duration,
          date: new Date(response.data.date),
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Functional

We provide a empty [dependency array](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) to only run when the component mounts

```js
function Component() {
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:5000/exercises/" +
          window.location.toString().split("/")[4]
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setUsername(response.data.username)
        // ...etc
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
},[])
}
```

---

3. Handling event, onClick, onChange

Class

```js
class Component {
  onChangeUsername(event) {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
  }
}
```

Functional

When rendering the element we can just use the state variable like `username` without the `this.state`. Same for the event handlers, no need for `this.`

```js
function Component() {
  function onChangeUsername(event) {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <input type="text" required value={username} onChange={onChangeUsername} />
  );
}
```